# loading recycler/listview items efficiently

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have an app that loads items from a `sql database` on my phone, what I do is I load the items from the `onResume()` method but looking at things its not the most efficient way, I can always see the items loading while when I look at other applications like `whatsApp` or `contacts` App one cannot even see the items loading. With my current way of loading my app is not only slow but also doing unnecessary processing, is there a better more efficient way any one knows that I can implement? thank you very much in advance.

Overview of my Sql Database Class:

```
public class Database  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//My list that holds my database items(which in my case is receipts)
private ArrayList<Receipt> allReceipts = new ArrayList<>();

  public ArrayList<Receipt> getAllReceipts() {
    try {
        allReceipts.clear();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Constants.RECEIPT_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if(cursor != null)
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                Receipt receipt  = new Receipt();
                receipt.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                receipt.setMerchantName(cursor.getString(1));
                receipt.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                allReceipts.add(receipt);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        if(cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return allReceipts;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("all_receipts", "" + e);
    }

    return allReceipts;
}
```

My Fragment Receiving the receipts

```
 private void initRecycler()
 {
    Action<List<ParentListItem>> action = new Action<List<ParentListItem>>() {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String id() {
            // Return a unique ID.
            return "load all receipts";
        }
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected List<ParentListItem> run() throws InterruptedException {
             receiptArrayList = database.getAllReceipts();
            return getReceipts();
        }

        @Override
        protected void done(@Nullable final List<ParentListItem> receipts) {
            progress.stop();

            assert receipts != null;
            if(receipts.isEmpty()) {



            }else {

                childAdapterListeners();



                adapter = new ReceiptExpandableAdapter(getContext(), receipts, onItemClickListenerCheckBtn, onItemClickListenerDeleteBtn, mOntemClickListenerViewBtn);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
               // recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
    };
    action.execute();
  }



  @Override
public void onResume()
{
   initRecycler();
   super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: Its really a broad question, many factors are there? Can u post the code?

Comment: in a moment please

Comment: try to fetch limited number of records (pages) of data. Fetch next previous pages only when user scrolls to them.

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending  CursorLoader? This is the most efficient and correct way of populating lists with database data.

Comment: could you please explain further

Comment: Of course. Please refer here http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html#InitializeLoader

Comment: This is the most efficient way of loading items from cursor. Also it's google recommended. As it manages cursors on configuration change. You can add method swapCursor to your recyclerview adapter quite easily.

Comment: The example shows how to use it with SimpleCursorAdapter.  However it's not difficult to implement with any custom adapter. Be that base adapter or recycler view adapter. You just need to provide the cursor in the adapter's constructor and swap it while loading is finished or reset. The CursorLoader extends AsyncLoader which in turn extends AsyncTask. Loading of data is therefore done on background thread and you get to override callbacks to ui Thread, when loader is finished or when it's been reset. You initialize your adapter in onLoaderFinished method. And set it to list.